# Return a value from a Signal handler inside a perl daemon

Tags: linux, perl, signals

How do I return a value to a process which initiated a daemon from a signal handler inside a daemon?

```
sub _fork
{
 my $pid = fork;
 $pid;
}
sub daemonize_monitor_sigio
{
    _fork and return;

    SIG{IO} = sub{
    print "caught sigio";
    $ret = {}
    ...#do some processing

    #wants to return $ret here;
    }
    while(1)
    {
    ;
    }
 }

daemoniz_monitor_sigio();
```

Comment: What does "called a daemon" mean? What does "return a value to a process" mean?

Comment: Please specify your problem better.  There are many ways to pass things around, and many ways for either to fail under specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about signal handlers, is they're pretty simple. They're basically an interrupt from the kernel, that's passed to the process.

The handler can alter state within the process. But because you've `fork()`ed beforehand, you have a parent process and a child process - the two don't have any shared state. So 'signaling' from one to the other, is an completely seperate [`IPC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) - at the simplest level - you can send another `kill` signal to the parent process - and get this pid via [`getpgrp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpgrp.html).

For more complicated IPCs though, you're looking at... well, reading the `perlipc` doc, and figuring out what's most appropriate.